# Keep UITableView selected value after data reload

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a table that is loading values from a JSON call that refreshes every 5 seconds. Every time the table changes, and a new cell is added, the currently selected cell becomes the one above the last one on the reload. You can see in my get_counter selector where I am trying to do it. Thanks in advance! I am still very new at ObjC so just trying to learn :)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
repeat_timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(check_new) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void)check_new{

    NSString *ret;
    ret=[MyWebFunction is_new_orders:appDelegate.user_id Order_number:[[response_array objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"order_id"] Type:type];

    if([ret isEqualToString:@"yes"]){
        [indicator startAnimating];
        [self performSelector:@selector(get_counter) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0005];

    }
}


-(void)get_counter{

jsonString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:[MyWebFunction get_orders:appDelegate.user_id Type:type Limit:limit] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];;
response_array = [[jsonString JSONValue] retain];
[indicator stopAnimating];

//this is my attempt at retaining the value :)    
NSIndexPath *ipath = [table indexPathForSelectedRow];
NSLog(@"iPath: %@",ipath);
[table reloadData];
[table selectRowAtIndexPath:ipath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];


if([response_array count]>0){

    total=[[[response_array objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"total_orders"] intValue];
    checksArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(int i=0;i<response_array.count;i++){

        [checksArray addObject:@"0"];
    }
}
sel_item_id=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
all_ids=nil;

if(repeat_timer){
    [repeat_timer invalidate];
    repeat_timer=nil;
repeat_timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(check_new) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I could be totally off on this one but this might be you problem.

```
NSIndexPath *ipath = [table indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

To me this looks like your getting a pointer the selected row. So when you update the table ipath gets updated also.

try:

```
NSIndexPath *ipath = [[table indexPathForSelectedRow] copy];
```

The other thing is, if your adding a new row then the row indices have changes. 
try this instead:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
```

so it would be:

```
NSIndexPath *ipath = [table indexPathForSelectedRow];
UITableViewCell *cell = [table cellForRowAtIndexPath:ipath];
[table reloadData];
[table selectRowAtIndexPath:[table indexPathForCell:cell] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

Lot of information but hopefully something in there will help.

Comment: Thanks Jaybit...That didnt work though. :(

When I do an NSLog of ipath, it comes up as null so it might be that it is in a different class that the row gets selected or something?

Comment: "indexPathForSelectedRow
Returns an index path identifying the row and section of the selected row.

- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForSelectedRow
Return Value
An index path identifying the row and section indexes of the selected row or nil if the index path is invalid." From UITableView CLass Reference